# Explanation of this integral's solution

Tags: integration, geometry, circles

While doodling around with circles and associated geometry, I've stumbled across this integral (I'm led to believe it is correct but I have not found or created any proof):

$$2\int_{-r}^{r}\sqrt{r^2-x^2}dx=\pi r^2;r \ge 0 \tag 1$$

(edit, changed $\sqrt{r-x^2}$ to $\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$ as the former is not correct geometrically)

If it isn't immediately clear, this resulted from using an infinite series of parallel chords to compute area. I'm aware there are simpler approaches, however this one is intriguing, knowing the result... I've tried integrating it by hand, couldn't figure out how to approach it.

Wolfram Alpha (for lack of human assistance at my disposal) gave me this [fascinating indefinite integral for $r=1$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sqrt%281-x%5E2%29):

$$F(x)=\int\sqrt{1-x^2}dx=\frac{1}2(x\sqrt{1-x^2}+\arcsin x) \tag 2$$

It is apparent that: $2(F(1)-F(-1))=(\arcsin{1}) - (\arcsin{-1}) = \pi$

I understand why to *expect* $\arcsin$ to appear in the result, after all $\sqrt{1-x^2}=\cos\arcsin x$, but I don't understand *why* it has appeared in the result or its significance. I can see already that any definite integral for (1) will cancel itself out leaving only the arcsin term...

A step-by-step solution to (1) or (2) would be most helpful but not required.

Comment: Whoopsies.... There's a mistake in (1). should be $\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$....

Comment: The arcsin  appears because its derivative is $1/\sqrt{1-x^2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining $x=r\cos(\theta)$ we can find that $\text{d}x=-r\sin(\theta)\text{d}\theta$ and $\theta$ goes from $\pi$ to $0$ the integral becomes $$\int_{-r}^{r}\sqrt{r^2-x^2}\text{d}x=-r\int_{\pi}^{0}\sqrt{r^2-r^2\cos^2(\theta)}\sin(\theta)\text{d}\theta=-r^2\int_{\pi}^{0}\sin^2(\theta)\text{d}\theta$$ and you may continue.

Answer (score 2):

By recalling 
$$\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1,$$ 
we are tempted to make a substitution $x = \sin t$ in $(2)$. Then, the indefinite integral becomes
$$\int \sqrt{1-\sin^2t} \cos t \,dt = \int \cos^2 t \, dt.$$
Using integration by parts you will get your desired result.

What similar substitution can you do in order to solve $(1)$?

Comment: This is very helpful, I really wish I could mark both.... My fault for asking for multiple forms of answers...

Answer (score 1):

By decomposition, then by parts,
$$\int\sqrt{1-x^2}dx=\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}-\int\frac{x^2\,dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\arcsin(x)+x\sqrt{1-x^2}-\int\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx.$$

You can conclude.

Answer (score 0):

The integral that you want to compute is the area of a circle segment defined by intersecting the trigonometric circle with a vertical at $x$.

[image]

This area is that of the sector, equal to the subtended angle, minus the triangle.

$$A=2\int_{-1}^x\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx=2\arcsin(x)+x\sqrt{1-x^2}.$$